# Error: "Cannot resolve symbol R"

Tags: android

I have written some code in my MainActivity.java and everywhere "R" is mentioner it turns red and says "symbol r cannot be resolved". If you want my MainActivity, please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do share your code / relevant config to help people to answer your question.

Comment: We shouldn't have to ask - if you want help please post relevent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only the 'R' is red, it means there is something wrong with your R file(found at build\generated\source\r\debug\com\domain.projectname\R). Don't go around editing your R file- reason explained below*. There are a few possible solutions:

1) You might have written import android.R; on the top of your Activity. You need to have a different R file imported. This means, if your domain is example and your project name is project then replace with: import com.example.project.R

2) R is a build file. That means it disappears when you clean and generates a new one when you build(*this is the reason you don't edit your R file.. it's useless!). Make sure you build or rebuild your project after cleaning it.

3) Maybe your gradle project sync has not completed. Wait until all processes have finished running!

4) It is also possible your R file is corrupt or missing. If the above don't work, you can come to this conclusion. It has a very easy fix, because as I explained earlier when you rebuild.. a new R file is generated! So, just navigate to Build and click Clean project, then when that's done, click Rebuild project. With the new R file your problems should be gone.